# Structure of the proof for showing $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$ iff $f$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am currently proving the following set theory question for a real analysis course:

> Given a function $f : S \to T$ and $A \subset S$ establish the following: $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$, with equality for all $A$ iff $f$ is injective.

I do not need help with the details of this proof, however, I am struggling to understand how I should write and format it. Is this question really asking to show $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$ iff $f$ is injective?

If so, do I assume $f$ is injective for both set inclusions ($A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$ and $f^{-1}(f(A)) \subseteq A$ to show equality) or do I simply show $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$ iff $f$ is injective? I just want to make sure I am answering this question in full.

Comment: First, show the general inclusion $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$. Then, show that the reverse inclusion holds iff $f$ is injective.

Comment: It isn't true for just one $A.$ It is asking you to prove: $$\left(\forall A\subseteq X:A=f^{-1}(f(A))\right)\iff \left(f\text{ is injective}\right)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - So, as David said above: Show the general inclusion that $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$ then show *for every* $A \subseteq S$ , $f^{-1}(f(A)) \subseteq A$ if and only if $f$ is injective?

Comment: Yes. It is easier to prove that $$\tezxt{not injective} \implies $\exists A: A\neq f^{-1}(f(A)).$ Namely, given $f(x)=f(y)$ with $x\neq y,$ let $A=\{x\}$, then $\{x,y\}\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A).$

Comment: By the way, in this case it is easier tp prove that $\lnot A\iff \lnot B$ which is equivalent to $A\iff B.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove the first theorem alone: $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A)).$

Then, instead of the stated theorem, show the equivalent, and more easily shown:

$$\left(\exists A: A\neq f^{-1}(f(A))\right)\iff (f\text{ is not injective})$$

This is equivalent because $P\iff Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot P\iff \lnot Q,$ and $\lnot \forall A: P(A)$ is equivalent to $\exists A:\lnot P(A).$

First assume $f$ is not injective. Then $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x\neq y.$ Then let $A=\{x\}.$ You see that $y\in f^{-1}(f(A))$ so $f^{-1}(f(A))\neq A.$

Assume $A\neq f^{-1}(f(A)).$  Now, $A\subsetneq f^{-1}(f(A))$ so there must be a $y\in f^{-1}(f(A))$ such that $y\notin A.$ From there, prove that $f$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quantify over the $A$ too!

So $f: S \to T$ is injective iff

$$\forall A \subseteq S: A = f^{-1}(f(A))\tag{i}$$

This is not very hard. For proof of injectivity of $f$ from $(i)$ we only need to consider $A$ that have two elements.

Comment: I think where my confusion lies is this: How is it possible to have a set $ f^{-1}(f(A)) := \{x \in S: f(x) \in f(A)\}$ where the elements of the set are in $S$, however their image lies in $f(A)$. How can this be? For an element's image to be in $f(A)$ doesn't it need to be in $A$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon no, e.g. if $f(x)=x^2$ is defined on the reals and $A=(0,+\infty)$ then $x=-1$ has image in $ f(A)$ while not being in $A$.

Comment: gotcha. How does the definition of $f(A)$ allow this though? It’s defined as $\{f(x): x \in A \}$.

Comment: @TaylorRendon so $ y \in f(A)$ iff $ \exists a \in A: f(a)=y$.

Comment: So if $x \in S$ such that $f(x) \in f(A)$ then $\exists$ $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = f(x)$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon yes, a point can have more than one point mapping to it, one in $A$ and one not e.g.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\colon S \to T$, remember that $U\subset S \rightarrow$ $f^{-1}({\color{red}U}) = \{x\in S : f(x) \in {\color{red}U}\} $,then:

$$f^{-1}({\color{red}{f(A)}}) = \{x\in S: f(x) \in {\color{red}{f(A)}}\}$$

Now note that for all $x\in A$, $f(x)\in f(A)$ is always true, so for all $x\in A, x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$.

**NOTE**
You have to take care of $f(x)\in f(A)$. This doesn't imply $x\in A$. As you can see in this graph, $f(A)=f(B)$, so if $x\in f(A)$,  then $f^{-1}(A) $ can be $A$, $B$, or another set in $S$. equality only holds if $f$ is injective (why? :D)

[image: note]